# CentOS 6.2 there is no slapd.conf after installating openldap

Tags: linux, centos, openldap

I have just installed fresh Centos 6.2 with openldap and samba with yum command. I'm having a bit of issue with finding the slapd.conf file. There is a folder for slap.d/ but no conf file in it by default. I can see folders

```
cacerts 
schema
sldap.d
```

and ldap.conf file.

I have also checked in Fedora 15 and found same situation that there is no slapd.conf file. So now where to start? I have googled but I found openldap configurations with Centos 5.x or Ubuntu which is following the configuration file from /etc/openldap/slapd.conf

Answer (score 10):

> Note that OpenLDAP no longer reads its configuration from the /etc/openldap/slapd.conf file. Instead, it uses a configuration database located in the /etc/openldap/slapd.d/ directory.

Source: [The official upstream documentation for RHEL7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/openldap)

> The slapd configuration consists of LDIF entries organized in a hierarchical directory structure, and the recommended way to edit these entries is to use the server utilities described in [Section 16.1.2.1, “Overview of OpenLDAP Server Utilities”](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Directory_Servers.html#s3-ldap-packages-openldap-servers).

In other words, RHEL6 (and CentOS6) no longer has a single slapd.conf file to configure openldap. You should use the tools lised in section 16.1.2.1 to configure openldap.

If you have an old config you wish to import, you can do that using this command:
`slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well I does not know from where I should take my 1st step to configure openldap server.This is a new style & on the google I mostly found the complete configuration for how to configure openldap server using old method i.e slapd.conf file.Can you kindly write the steps so I may fallow them ? Shouuld be thankfull

Comment: You can convert using `slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/` as shown in the documentation linked.